# Is it possible to use a dynamic value in asp-route-{value}?

Tags: html, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have Razor Page with the following piece of code to create a link that adds a dynamic value to the route when clicked. This works perfectly.

```
<a class="page-link" asp-route-systemRightsPage="@(i.Index)">@i.Index</a>
```

Now, I have different values for the route, in this case I'm using `systemRightsPage`, but I also have 3 more types that I can navigate to (`personsPage`, `personRightsPage`, `errorsPage`), and so on.

Is it possible to use somehow a dynamic value on the `asp-route-{value}` part?
I tried using this:

```
<a class="page-link" asp-route-@(RouteValue)="@(i.Index)">@i.Index</a>
```

This code renders correctly in HTML to:

```
<a class="page-link" asp-route-personpage="2">2</a>
```

But the link doesn't work anymore, as nothing happens if I click it.

Has anyone done anything similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `all-route-data` attribute to pass arbitrary parameter names and their values:

```
@{var values = new Dictionary<string,string>{{"personpage", "2"}};}

<a asp-page="/whatever" asp-all-route-data="values">Click</a>
```

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/anchor-tag-helper

Comment: Very well explained! I was not aware of `all-route-data`, this works perfectly, thanks!